# sed: remove extra whitespace to single whitespace between strings while leaving leading tabs intact

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, tr, whitespace

I have a code:

```
1 /**             
2 a        b         c
3 **/
4 int main() {
5     int x;
6     if ( condition) {
7     return       x;
8     }
9 }
```

I need to change multiple whitespaces between tokens or strings to single whitespace eg in line 7 but comments (line 2) should not be affected nor the leading tabs in the code. So, the output should be:

```
1 /**             
2 a        b         c
3 **/
4 int main() {
5     int x;
6     if ( condition) {
7     return x;
8     }
9 }
```

I tried using 'tr': `~$ tr -s " " < file` but it changed line 2 as well as removed leading tabs in line 5 to line 8. Can it be done using `sed`?

Comment: Parsing C comments is the hard part here.

Comment: I think it will have to be greedy like cat input | sed 's/\(return\)\( *\)\(x\)/\1 \3/g' > output

Comment: What should happen with `printf("some     spacey      words\n");` where the words have more than one space between them? (the markup here removes the multiple spaces between the words).

Comment: I think you'd be better off with using a proper C code formatter such as `indent` or `clang-format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How far would

```
sed -rn '\#/\*\*#,\#\*\/*# {p;b}; s/([^ ]) +/\1 /g; p' file
```

get you? It prints the comment lines unmodified (can't deal with comment on / off in the same line, though) and skips the rest of the script. For uncommented lines, it squeezes any multiple spaces following a non-space char (so line indentation is out of scope) to a single space.

Comment: great, worked ! An explanation would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this worked for me:

`sed -i 's/\([a-zA-Z]\+\)\(  *\)\([a-zA-Z]\+\)/\1 \3/g' $1`

Comment: This doesn't seem to leave the comments alone?

Comment: but in mine it does, I dont know how. I had a deadline so this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/^ [\d+ " "?] \t* \H+? <(" " ** 2..*)> / /;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's/^ [\d+ " "?] \c[TAB]* \H+? <(\c[SPACE] ** 2..*)> / /;'  file
```

The Raku code above quite literally differentiates between tabs (`\t` or `\c[TAB]` and spaces (`" "` or `\c[SPACE]`).

The `-pe` flags run code linewise over the input, with autoprinting. The regex searches from the `^` beginning-of-the-string for `[\d+ " "?]` digits followed by 0-or-1 space, followed by an optional tab, followed (non-greedily) by `\H+?` one-or-more non-horizontal-whitespace characters, followed by  `2..*` two-or-more spaces. The `<(`...`)>` capture markers drop everything from the match except the final two-or-more spaces, which are replaced with a single space.

Omit the bracketed `[\d+ " "?]` group if no line numbers. Only one substitution per line, so may have to be run multiple times if multiple spaced characters at the right end of the line.

Sample Input:

```
1 /**             
2 a\tb\tc
3 **/
4 int main() {
5\tint x;
6\tif ( condition) {
7\treturn       x;
8\t}
9 }
```

Sample Output:

```
1 /** 
2 a\tb\tc
3 **/
4 int main() {
5\tint x;
6\tif ( condition) {
7\treturn x;
8\t}
9 }
```

Of course, the answer above is predicated upon characters-within-comment-blocks being separated by tabs, instead of multiple-spaces. Maybe the best way to ensure ***that*** is to *pre-run* a substitution for comment blocks specifically:

```perl
~$ raku -pe 'state $ph;                     \
             $ph = 1 if /^  "/**"  \s* $/;  \
             $ph = 0 if /^  "**/"  \s* $/;  \
             s:g/" " ** 4/\t/ if  $ph == 1 ;'   file
```

The code above will substitute one tab for every 4 spaces, only within comment blocks. Add back in the bracketed `[\d+ " "?]` group just after the `^` in the second and third statements, if each line starts with a line-number.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701572/227738
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org